FreeRadius EAP-TLS with Windows Client looping request
I have a FreeRadius 3.0 setup with EAP-TLS only configuration using the test CA, server cert and client cert supplied in the FreeRadius package.

CA.der is installed in Trusted Root Authority Store.
Client.p12 is installed in User's Personal Store.
Wifi profile is setup to not verify server identity.

When I try to authenticate with the SSID, the process runs indefinitely on windows client. FreeRadius -X shows requests are being received indefinitely.
I've made sure the server.pem has the required OID. I've been at this for this entire week and can't figure out what is going on.
Here's the FreeRadius log:
freeradius  | (11) Found Auth-Type = eap

freeradius  | (11) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default

freeradius  | (11)   authenticate {

freeradius  | (11) eap: Removing EAP session with state 0x9573bc9d9771b1e2

freeradius  | (11) eap: Previous EAP request found for state 0x9573bc9d9771b1e2, released from the list

freeradius  | (11) eap: Peer sent packet with method EAP TLS (13)

freeradius  | (11) eap: Calling submodule eap_tls to process data

freeradius  | (11) eap_tls: (TLS) Peer ACKed our handshake fragment

freeradius  | (11) eap: Sending EAP Request (code 1) ID 3 length 989

freeradius  | (11) eap: EAP session adding &reply:State = 0x9573bc9d9670b1e2

freeradius  | (11)     \[eap\] = handled

freeradius  | (11)   } # authenticate = handled

freeradius  | (11) Using Post-Auth-Type Challenge

freeradius  | (11) # Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default

freeradius  | (11)   Challenge { ... } # empty sub-section is ignored

freeradius  | (11) session-state: Saving cached attributes

freeradius  | (11)   Framed-MTU = 994

freeradius  | (11)   TLS-Session-Information = "(TLS) TLS - recv TLS 1.3 Handshake, ClientHello"

freeradius  | (11)   TLS-Session-Information = "(TLS) TLS - send TLS 1.2 Handshake, ServerHello"

freeradius  | (11)   TLS-Session-Information = "(TLS) TLS - send TLS 1.2 Handshake, Certificate"

freeradius  | (11)   TLS-Session-Information = "(TLS) TLS - send TLS 1.2 Handshake, ServerKeyExchange"

freeradius  | (11)   TLS-Session-Information = "(TLS) TLS - send TLS 1.2 Handshake, CertificateRequest"

freeradius  | (11)   TLS-Session-Information = "(TLS) TLS - send TLS 1.2 Handshake, ServerHelloDone"

freeradius  | (11) Sent Access-Challenge Id 24 from 172.18.0.2:1812 to 194.83.172.40:51181 length 1053

freeradius  | (11)   EAP-Message = 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

freeradius  | (11)   Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000

freeradius  | (11)   State = 0x9573bc9d9670b1e2b9f2be3cbfa12588

freeradius  | (11) Finished request

freeradius  | Waking up in 4.8 seconds.

freeradius  | (8) Cleaning up request packet ID 21 with timestamp +481 due to cleanup_delay was reached

freeradius  | (9) Cleaning up request packet ID 22 with timestamp +481 due to cleanup_delay was reached

freeradius  | (10) Cleaning up request packet ID 23 with timestamp +481 due to cleanup_delay was reached

freeradius  | (11) Cleaning up request packet ID 24 with timestamp +481 due to cleanup_delay was reached

freeradius  | Ready to process requests


Judging by the log you have an issue with the challenge-response part of opening a session.
Freeradius is sending a challenge to be passed on by the access point to the client, but does not get a response the other way.
And since there is no response, then the WiFi connection cannot be established.
But without you telling how you have configured Freeradius and the access point, then we have no way of telling why challenge-response does not work.
